# fazer click de um botão dar play no iframe do Youtube

Tags: jquery, html

Tenho um `iframe` do Youtube, e uma `div` por cima dela, quero que quando o usuário clique em cima dessa `div` ele dê o play no vídeo.
Meu HTML:

```
<div class="p-relative">
    <div class="botaoMaior">
        <div class="btplay"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="editable videoMaior" name="videoMaior">
    <iframe width="960" height="780" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/eX0IjD5DPQI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Eu gostaria de algo do tupo:

```
 $( ".botaoMaior" ).click(function() {
  $( ".botaoTeste" ).click();
});
```

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/play-button-youtube-and-vimeo-api/

Comment: @JorgeB. não sei se é bem exatamente isso que eu preciso. Tá um pouco complexa essa explicação.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Você pode fazer de uma maneira bem simplificada usando o parâmetro `autoplay=1` na querystring:

```
$('#image_id').click(function() {
    $(".frameVideo").attr('src', $(".frameVideo").attr('src') + '?autoplay=1'); 
});

<button id="image_id">Play</button>
<iframe class="frameVideo" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/eX0IjD5DPQI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Aonde `image_id` é o id de sua imagem ou botão clicável e `.frameVideo` é a classe do `<iframe>`

Exemplo online (os snippets rodam em SandBox e por isto não suporta o cross-origin):
http://jsfiddle.net/ngtdvyaj/

Comment: tentei da seguinte forma e não deu certo http://jsfiddle.net/felipestoker/cp6xa0rk/

Comment: atualizei a parte do frame da uma olhada

Comment: Ele ativou o play, só que ao invés de abrir o vídeo, ele mostrou isso http://pastebin.com/9BFwJPdy

Comment: youtube bloqueado no trabalho .... rsrsrs so a noite

Comment: tudo bem, eu só achei estranho esse erro, parece coisa do server, mas não tem ligação nenhuma

Comment: @FelipeStoker seu exemplo não funcionou (http://jsfiddle.net/felipestoker/cp6xa0rk/) por que você não adicionou o jquery aos resources :( e você usou o seletor `.frameVideo iframe`, mas o Otto forneceu o exemplo assim: `.videoMaior iframe` (que é o correto), a classe `frameVideo` já pertence ao `<iframe>`. Note que o `, parent)` não existe também. Código corrigido: http://jsfiddle.net/cp6xa0rk/1/

Comment: opa tuda a ajuda é bem vinda

Comment: Seu exemplo funcinou @Otto

Comment: perfeito @FelipeStoker

Answer (score 14):

Inclua o script da API do youtube e substitua seu `iframe` por uma `div` com um id para poder identificá-la:

```
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>

<div class="editable videoMaior" name="videoMaior">
    <div id="meuPlayer"></div>
</div>
```

Depois, no JS, você pode utilizar a API como na [documentação](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference):

```
var player = new YT.Player('meuPlayer', {
    width: 540,
    height: 320,
    videoId: 'eX0IjD5DPQI'
});

$(".botaoMaior").on("click", function() {
    player.playVideo();
});
```

[Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u06oowLn/)

Neste exemplo, a `div#meuPlayer` server para identificar o lugar onde o `iframe` será inserido. O `iframe` irá **substituir** a `div`. Ao chamar o método `YT.Player`, um novo objeto referente ao player do vídeo será criado e retornado, o qual pode ser utilizado para controlar as funções do player de diversas formas. Veja [neste link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls) as funções disponíveis para este objeto.

Comment: o Iframe vai dentro da div `meuPlayer`?

Comment: Não, a api vai sobrescrever a `div` pelo `iframe`.

Comment: como eu eu eu farei pra deixar o `videoId` gerenciável?

Answer (score 7):

Você não pode manipular os documento DOM de um iframe que aponta para um domínio diferente da pagina que o contem. O que você pode fazer neste caso para ter um controle maior sobre o player é utlizar a API do Youtube Embbed.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=pt-br

Utilizando a API você poderia ter algo como o trecho abaixo para reproduzir o video.

```
$( ".botaoMaior" ).click(function() {
    player.playVideo();
});
```